# Как убрать вторую часть кнопки в шаблоне Вордпресс

Tags: php

Есть шаблон Easy Store, в нём кнопка добавить в корзину и кнопка добавить в список желаемого это ода кнопка разделённая на две части, мне надо часть с Добавить в список желаемого удалить. Перепробовал всё, помогите пож.
по моему вот эта часть кода

`

```
// end product cart section wrapper
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'easy_store_product_buttons_wrap_close', 15 );
function easy_store_product_buttons_wrap_close() {
    echo '</div><!-- .es-product-buttons-wrap -->';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'easy_store_wishlist_button', 20 );
function easy_store_wishlist_button() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'YITH_WCWL' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    global $product;
    $product_id = yit_get_product_id( $product );
    $current_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_type = $current_product->get_type();
?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'add_to_wishlist', intval( $product_id ) ) )?>" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>" data-product-type="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_type ); ?>" class="add_to_wishlist" >
        <?php
            $easy_store_wishlist_text = apply_filters( 'easy_store_product_wishlist_text', __( 'В избранное', 'easy-store' ) );
            echo esc_html( $easy_store_wishlist_text );
        ?>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл сам решение, в CSS поменял ширину кнопки с 50% на 100%.